# How can I create a Azure Web Application to authenticate User and acquire its Access Token?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to create an Azure Web Application that can authenticate an external/internal (from any Organization) user upon opening the Web Application link through Azure AD Credentials and acquire its Access token in return.

I want to use that Access Token to programmatically create an application registration in User's tenant.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to [register an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) and set it as a [multi-tenant application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-registration-to-be-multi-tenant), then use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to authenticate the user and obtain an access token.

Next, you need to use the access token to call the [MS graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create an application, because you are using the auth code flow to obtain the token, so you need to grant `delegation permissions` to the application.

see: [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2-signInAndCallGraph).

Comment: Hi Carl. Thank you for the above articles. I was able to get the Access token. I also wanted to know if there is a way I can get the details of Subscription ID and Tenant ID of the Logged in User?