# How to get the Account Id (Subscription Id) and Tenant Id of a user logged in my Web Application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api

For reference this is in continuation to my previous question here
[How can I create a Azure Web Application to authenticate User and acquire its Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088908/how-can-i-create-a-azure-web-application-to-authenticate-user-and-acquire-its-ac)

I was able to get the Access Token with the help of [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2-signInAndCallGraph).

I now need to also programmatically fetch Subscription Id and Tenant Id of the User that has logged in the above created Web Application.

The values are going to be used in my Powershell Function App for the Command :

```
Connect-AzureAD -AadAcessToken $AccessToken -TenantId $TenantId -AccountId $AccountId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Account id is the upn (email) of the user.

Use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=userPrincipalName` to get the upn. Example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-signed-in-user-request).

```
var user = await graphClient.Me
    .Request()
    .Select("userPrincipalName")
    .GetAsync();
```

And use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization?$select=id` to get the tenant id. Example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example).

```
var organization = await graphClient.Organization
    .Request()
    .Select("id")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Hi Allen. Thanks for the response. I was able to get the Tenant ID. Instead of the User UPN, I actually need the Subscription Id of the User. I could not find any documentation related to this. Do you know if this is possible? Thanks

Comment: @Saurab Microsoft Graph mainly manages the AAD resources. But Azure subscription is a different part from AAD. I'm afraid that you can't get the subscription id using Microsoft Graph. You could use [AzureRM Powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0) to get the subscription id: `Login-AzureRmAccount  $context = Get-AzureRmContext  $subscription = $context.Subscription.Id`.